# Subdivision causes this weird thing

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I am very new to blender and trying to make a coffee cup lid which has sharp edges. I used the Edge Split modifier which fixed some of the issues i previously had but subdivision causes this weird thing and idk how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: hello, the best would be to fix your topology with some additional edge loops, you should show the picture of what you're trying to achieve and share your file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's simply how the *Subdivision Surface* modifier works. It tries to round all edges to smooth them. The less geometry there is or the further away two edges are from each other, the more round or smooth it will be there.

So, to makes edges sharper, to need to have more geometry i.e. there need to be edges closer together. Like @moonboots said in his comment, additional edge loops might help here.

What you did with the *Edge Split* modifier is sharpening edges, too - but in this case, Blender assumes a split edge as two separate parts, which means they will stay completely sharp even with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. No slight smoothing even if desired.

Take a look at the image below, the left and bottom sides of the object have edge loops close to the bounding edges - more geometry, sharper edges. The right and top sides have no additional edge loops - they are rounded off stronlgy.

[image: edge loops]